# Custom PC won't boot Windows 7 DVD but does with Windows Vista

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, motherboard, dvd

I ordered a custom-built PC (assembled by the store). This is the setup:

- Motherboard: Asrock A75 PRO4-M
- DVD drive: LG GH24NS90
- SSD: Samsung 830 series 128 GB
- DDR3 SDRAM: 2× Corsair XMS3 CMX4GX3M1A1600C9 (2× 4 GB)
- APU (CPU+GPU): AMD A8-3850 Boxed

I got an installation DVD for Windows 7 Professional x64 English (including SP1), but it doesn't work. I then got a new one from the store and it doesn't work either. However they work on another PC, so the DVDs aren't bad.

I tried an old installation DVD for Windows Vista. Both 32-bit and 64-bit work. So the boot order and such are right and working on the new PC.

Is there something I'm missing here? Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? Are you saying that the PC doens't boot up at all, or that the DVD isn't detected, or the DVD is detected but doesn't load. Can the BIOS see the DVD drive?

Comment: The PC does boot (as it works with the Windows Vista DVD).

The PC tries to read the Windows 7 for a minute or two and then concludes it is not working and asks to insert a DVD.

Comment: It's okay. There is no OS installed at all (as the PC is completely new). 

Could it really be the DVD when it works with different DVDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, as the BIOS see's the DVD drive but the DVD won't run (despite running on other machines) it suggests the DVD drive's optic lens may be faulty, or may be it doesn't spin properly. Either way, as it's new, get a new DVD drive.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try that. I'll report back with results ;)

Comment: Actually, as it's a new build I'd take the whole thing to the shop and make them do it! The OS install only takes a little while, you can shop while you wait :) But, at least they will then find the actual cause and you know you'll leave the shop with a working PC.

Comment: It's an online store, but I'll contact them to see what my options are.

Comment: We took the DVD drive from the PC of a colleague who isn't at work today and it works ;)

Comment: Just use a USB-based setup in future. Far less hassle and much faster too!